# DispatcherTimer Tick event stopped after exception in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

We have used DispatcherTimer for updating datetime in label in WPF Application.

Its tick event stopped working after exception.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();            
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();
```

We have added Dispactch undhandled exception to catch all unhandled exception.

```
this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Dispatcher_UnhandledException);
```

Error call of DispatcherTimer tick event (devide by zero ). After exception application handled the call to UnhandledException & then stopped calling DispatcherTimer tick event.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerClock = ServerClock.AddSeconds(1);

            int a = 0;
            int i = 1 / a;

        }
```

What is stopping tick event to run in another tick?

Comment: DispatcherTimer (correctly) concludes that your Tick handler is broken, and never calls it again. Your handler must not raise an exception. Adding an UnhandledException handler to your application's Dispatcher (which btw is not a DispatcherTimer) doesn't change that.

Comment: could [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759814/dispatchertimer-tick-event-handler-is-swallowing-exception) be of interest?

Comment: What is the work around for this? We are using unhandled exception for some of the business logic. As mentioned by @Default this is because of swalling of excetion ([link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759814/dispatchertimer-tick-event-handler-is-swallowing-exception) )

Answer (score 0):

> What is stopping tick event to run in another tick?

The unhandled exception. As noted in the comments, if an exception is thrown from the timer tick handler, by design your handler won't be called again. The "work-around" is to either avoid throwing exceptions in the first place, or if that is simply not possible, to *handle* the exception in a graceful way.

If you cannot avoid the exception and cannot handle it gracefully (i.e. in some way more elegant and precise than just adding `try { } catch (Exception) { }`), then your code is broken and needs to be fixed. That's a whole other question though.

Note that `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` is exactly what its name implies: it's an event that is raised when an *unhandled* exception occurs.

Importantly, subscribing a handler to that event does not cause the exception itself to become handled. It's still *unhandled*. It's just that now you have a way of knowing that there was in fact an unhandled exception.

Since subscribing to the event doesn't cause the exception to be handled, doing so also doesn't in any way change the behavior of the timer when an exception occurs.

Finally, I'll note that there are at least two other timer classes, and at least one other asynchronous timing mechanism in .NET that could be used in a WPF program. It's possible (I didn't check and don't recall off the top of my head) that one or more of those would continue to raise tick events even if your handler throws an exception. But a) using one of those other mechanisms may complicate your code in other ways, and b) doing so won't in any way change the fact that as it stands now, your code is fundamentally incorrect and needs fixing.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, we are using the unhandled exception to log the errors & so on. But what is more important that dispatcher timer tick event is not throwing any exception but whenever unhandled exception event call, dispatcher timer tick event is stopped working. May be I asked different question, but main problem is that dispatcher timer tick event stop working whenever application unhandled exception event called.

Comment: "timer tick event is not throwing any exception" -- I don't understand this claim. The code example clearly shows that it does throw `DivideByZeroException`. Plus, you even acknowledge the unhandled exception is in fact reported. Why do you think you can claim that the event handler is _not_ "throwing any exception"?